# Adding Record to Related Table using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping

I looked and didn't find this question so hopefully it isn't a repeat.

I am new to the JavaScript API and just started creating a web application where the user will enter maintenance records for a street light. The street lights are shown as points on the map, and the maintenance table is a related table that in joined to the street light based on the street ID. When the user clicks the street light, a pop up currently appears with information of the street light. I also have a button (that currently does nothing) and that the user will hopefully be able to select to bring up a window to enter a new maintenance record for that street light. However, I am not sure how to precede with this. Doing some looking, I have seen there is a EDITOR widget, but that seems to be for adding features that have geometries. However, my records will not have geometries.

Thanks for any help, and please ask any questions if my question was not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESRI has a JS sample that's not exactly the same, but similar.  Might be helpful to review as a lot of the concepts could be used in what you're trying to do most likely.

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/ed_relatededits.html