# Using AttributeInspector to Create New Record

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-mapping

This is a follow up question to another questions I posted earlier:
[Adding Record to Related Table using JavaScript API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/74338/19882)

Without repeating too much information from that previous question, I was able to figure out how to use ApplyEdits to add a (hard-coded) record to the related table. Now, when the user clicks on the button to "Add Record", I want a popup/info window to appear that has all of the attributes from the table, and that the user can enter the new information into for each attribute. Doing some research, I saw that the AttributeInspector will bring up the fields/values for a feature, but it seems that it must already be created.

Does anyone know a way to use AttributeInspector or another method to retrieve all of the fields (and their domains) to create a new record in a table and not just edit an already existing one? Thanks.